# Writing complex query to count in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I need help in writing a query for below collections in MongoDB.

1. I need to count total no. of products ["data" contains the products] inside all active product groups
2. Groups is  active is status=1

Below is sample hierarchy of ProductGroups:

```
>ProductGroup1
 - Group1
   - product11
   - product12
     ...
 - Group2 
   - product21
>ProductGroup22
 - Group21
   - product211
   - product212
     ...
 - Group22
   - product221
...
```

Below is just sample of 1 product group. There can be many product groups.
Sample collections:

```
{"_id":ObjectId("abcd"), "_class":"PGroup", 
"name":"test", 
"status"=1, 
"groups": [
"name":"group1","data": [{"url":"urlofproduct1", "name":"product1"}, {"url":"urlofproduct2", "name":"product2"}, ...],
"name":"group2","data": [{"url":"urlofproduct1", "name":"product1"}, {"url":"urlofproduct2", "name":"product2"}, ...],
...
"name":"group10","data": [{"url":"urlofproduct1", "name":"product1"}, {"url":"urlofproduct2", "name":"product2"}, ...],
]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just re-structured your data to look like this:

```
/* 1 */
{
"_id" : "abcd",
"_class" : "PGroup",
"name" : "test",
"status" : 1,
"groups" : [ 
    {
        "name" : "group1",
        "data" : [ 
            {
                "url" : "urlofproduct1",
                "name" : "product1"
            }, 
            {
                "url" : "urlofproduct2",
                "name" : "product2"
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "name" : "group2",
        "data" : [ 
            {
                "url" : "urlofproduct1",
                "name" : "product1"
            }, 
            {
                "url" : "urlofproduct2",
                "name" : "product2"
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "name" : "group10",
        "data" : [ 
            {
                "url" : "urlofproduct1",
                "name" : "product1"
            }, 
            {
                "url" : "urlofproduct2",
                "name" : "product2"
            }
        ]
    }
 ]
}
```

Also, I hope you are trying to find total count of all products from all product groups. Try this query, if that's what you're looking for:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
 {$match:{status:1}},
 {$unwind:"$groups"},
 {$unwind:"$groups.data"},
 {$group:{_id:null,count:{$sum:1}}}
])
```

`count` will give you total number of products from all groups. If you need to find out total product count under each product group, query will be different, just do a `$group` on `_class` if thats what your requirement is. Hope that answers your question.